# How to know when you have a file open in vi while using the shell?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, ssh, vi

When I am editting a file in `vi` or `vim`, I frequently will be editting the file, and then I need to open a shell to execute a shell command.  So, I go to the shell by doing `:sh`.

This brings me to the shell.  Now, when I want to return to the file I'm editting, I will freqquently do `control + D` to return the file.  This works fine.  I followed the instructions [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~pcs/apps/editors/vi/vi_unix.html).

I do a lot of work on remote AWS machines which I am `ssh`-d into.  And, `control+D` is one way to exit those machines.  Unfortunately, while ssh-d into those machines, sometimes I do not know if I have a file open in `vi/vim` and when I do `control + D` to go back to the file, it exits my `ssh` session entirely.

Is there a way to either

- 1) know that I have a file currently open in vi or
- 2) exit the shell and go back to my file safely without risking accidentally closing my ssh session?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't send vi to the background with ctrl-z, do your shell work, then resume vi with ``fg``?

Comment: I've actually never heard of that command! that would be awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem you're having isn't trying to figure out whether vi is running but rather how to jump between the parent shell and vi using "job control" (grep for job control in the bash  or sh man page).

Use ctrl-z to background vi and use `fg` to resume. This works in all POSIX-derived shells and it works over ssh.

This is preferred over using `:sh` and ctrl-d since you avoid the problem you're having, you get the same shell that you were working with when you started vi, and you have one less shell running (this isn't often a performance issue but if you have a lot of shells running it's easier to look at their PIDs when needed).

There may be other reasons for `:sh` but the only one I know of is getting a shell in a vi session that wasn't started from a shell to begin with.

Having said that, `vi -r` (with no args) prints a list of swap files that subsumes the set of files open in vi. Commands like `vi -r |& grep -B 3 'still running'` are useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsof +D <dir> | grep REG`

Will give you all regular files opened in your directory

For more filtering you can specify user by -u as well.